# How can I get my cat comfortable around other cats after a traumatic fight?

Tags: cats, introducing-pets, new-pets

This is my first post so I am sorry if this question is irritating to anyone. I tried to search up the answer to this but I just found posts about re-introducing cats who fought each other. My cat got into a fight with a cat that he has not seen since the fight. I’m hoping some cat owners have advice for me. Sorry I’m advance that this post is a long one.

So about a year ago, my declawed cat, John, was in a fight with an aggressive cat. They got into it under the bed and the cat with claws was attacking and clawing at him. John wasn’t hurt but he was really freaked out when I separated them. Ever since, John has been super hostile towards every cat other than the girl cat he’s known since I adopted him. With her, he’ll snuggle and groom her and they never seriously fight. He’s not hostile towards her at all. He’s super affectionate and needy towards me and basically acts like I’m his mom- he was in the shelter since her was a kitten (3 years and declawed) and he loves kneading and suckling while laying on me.

I was living at my mom’s house recently where John saw other cats through a screen door (I wanted to introduce him to my mom’s cats in hopes he would have company) but whenever he sees a cat through the screen he would crouch down and just hiss and growl the whole time. These cats were sitting at a distance just looking at him, not minding him at all. The one time John got out and met one of the boy cats he ended up in a chase and I finally caught him just growling and hissing like crazy. Needless to say, he's having a hard time being around new cats. He was fine around my dad’s male cat before the fight-just the typical spats, prowling around each other, etc- but they could be around each other and seemed to warm up to each other eventually.

Back to my point: today I moved back in with my dad and met his new cat, Sam. Sam is super friendly to me and seemed VERY interested in my cat’s scent all over me. Very curious and constantly sniffing and rubbing against me. Since I got here he keeps trying to come into my room to meet this new cat he smells. John is not as enthusiastic. He isn’t as bad as he was with my mom’s cats; he keeps sniffing me after I hang out with Sam. He wasn’t hissing as much and he seemed interested in me opening the door to see what cat he keeps smelling on me but once he saw Sam he started growling and backed off to hide under the bed. Sam just keeps sitting outside my door and I have to work hard to keep him from running into my room when I go to open the door. He seems so interested in John, he’ll scratch at the door and meow when I won’t let him in.

Does anyone have advice on how I can make John more open to meeting new cats? I would like to get John to the point where I can let him roam around the house and be around the 2 cats here but right now he’s straight up antisocial and just growls and hisses at any cats he sees. I lived her a year or two ago and John was fine roaming around the house around another cat. Ever since the fight he’s just been so hostile towards any new cats.

I’d sorry this post is so long and if it sounds like I don’t know enough about cats getting along. Any advice would be appreciated on how I could make John more comfortable meeting new cats. Sam really seems interested in John and not like he wants to defend his territory and attack him. I’d love to hear about any tips on introducing cats to each other. For now they just have contact through the closed door.